# How to update a component in JSF 1.2 to hide when its rendered property is not satisfied?

Tags: jsf

I am using JSF 1.2 to build a form. It is created dynamically, which means that it will not always be the same fields, nor the same type of field (chebox, radio buttom, and others). Some of these fields are required, you know this thanks to the `v.required` property.

They ask me to display a * with a message that says "Required value" as soon as the page is loaded, so that the user does not have to press the accept button to know which fields are required or not. The problem is that the site has implemented error messages with FacesMessages that indicate with an "Incorrect characters" and also "Required value", so when the user loads the page for the first time my * appears with my message, and if the user presses the "Accept" button appears then the FacesMessages with the message "Value required"

This is how I build my *:

```
<h:outputText for="#{idUtil.For(v)}" ajaxRendered="true" value="*" styleClass="required" rendered="#{v.requerido and facesMessages.getCurrentMessagesForControl(idUtil.For(v)).size()==0}"
                                                                                    title="Required value" />
```

This is how it appears when I load the page for the first time:
[image] and this is how it appears when I press the accept button, the * that I am showing and the FacesMessages with the same message: [image]

How can I hide my * when FacesMessages appears? Is there any way to reRendered components by class? It cannot be by id because when these fields are generated dynamically they cannot have a static id

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use a selector to select all the outputtext belonging to the class required so that they revalue the rendered condition and by having a message for that variable the length of the list would be different from 0, therefore the * will be hidden.

```
<p:commandButton update="@(.required)" />
```

Comment: still appers, don't work..any other idea?

Comment: This is PrimeFaces specific, not plain JSF.

Comment: @JasperdeVries could you sugget any idea to this problem? I will apreciate a lot...